# Problem regarding Positive Semi definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $ S = \{A \in a^{n \times n}\mid x^T Ax = 0 , \forall x\in \mathbb{R^n},  A = A^T\} $.
Then

a.  $|S|=1$

b.  $|S|>1$

c. $|S|=\chi 0$

d. $|S|=0$

My attempt: I know that $x^T Ax = 0$ implies matrix A is skew symmetric.  Also, in the question it is given that A is a symmetric matrix. Hence I got zero matrix and so option d, but the actual answer is option a. Please may I know where did I go wrong and how to proceed.

Comment: $|S|$ refers to the cardinality of the set $S$. It is equal to $1$ because $S$ has only one element, namely, the zero matrix.